# PHPMyadmin show host instead localhost when login

Tags: docker, nginx, phpmyadmin

This is my first web stack using Docker with Nginx - PHP - MariaDB phpmyadmin for my side projects.
Everything work perfectly. But im confusing a bit about my phpmyadmin.

I noticed that when i login to phpmyadmin, why phpmyadmin pop-up a host-address behind my username?
Example: I have username call "test" - when i login to `myadminphp` , it show up error below

```bash
mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'test'@'192.168.0.4' (using password: YES)
```

When i create the user in `mariadb` terminal, it give me `test@localhost`, not `test'@'192.168.0.4'` .
By using

```sql
CREATE USER 'test'@'localhost';
```

Give my `test@localhost` user with full permission

```sql
GRANT ALL ON my_db.* TO 'test'@'localhost';
```

```sql
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

And i can login as user by using `mysql -u test -p`
That im confusing here.

What is occured in my case? Can i switch from 'test'@'192.168.0.4' to `test@localhost` in PHPmyadmin?

##### Docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.9'
services:
  web:
    image: nginx:latest
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
    # Use port 80
      - "80:80"
    # Copy default config file to default folder
    # By using volumes keywords
    volumes:
      - /home/hoangtho/Projects/:/usr/share/nginx/html/
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
  php:
    image: php:7.3-fpm-alpine
    restart: "always"
    build:
      context: './php/'
    volumes:
      - /home/hoangtho/Projects/:/usr/share/nginx/html/
    
# PHP
  mariadb:
    image: mysql
    restart: "always"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
# PHPMYADMIN
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
      PMA_HOST: mariadb
      PMA_HOSTS: localhost,127.0.0.1
      
    ports:
      - "81:80"
```

##### Nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name localhost;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    autoindex on;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

##### Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.3-fpm-alpine

RUN docker-php-ext-install  mysqli
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason this happens is because MySQL returns the error message based on how you're connecting to the server. When you connect to 'localhost' it uses sockets and when you connect through any other host (including 127.0.0.1) it uses TCP/IP networking. MySQL/MariaDB users require a host field, which can be localhost, an IP address or hostname, or the wildcard operator `%`. The catch is that the wildcard operator does not include localhost connections.

Since you are connecting to a database that is not running on the same server as phpMyAdmin, your connection is not through localhost, so your user cannot have the host field of 'locahost'. Switching to test@localhost will not work because the connection is not local due to how Docker networking functions.

The other part of the problem here is that you're telling phpMyAdmin to connect to three servers, mariadb, localhost, and 127.0.0.1, which is odd and probably not needed. Based on what you've described, you should completely remove the array PMA_HOSTS from your docker-compose.yml and keep the `PMA_HOST: mariadb`.

So tweak your PMA_HOSTS and change your user to be @'%' or @'192.168.0.4', that should resolve these problems.